# What is the conjugation capacity of the liver?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, pathology, liver

Our liver conjugates 250-300 mg bilirubin per day under normal circumstances but it is capable of conjugating much more. What is the upper end per day after which it won’t be able to conjugate leading to increased unconjugated bilirubin in serum?

Comment: Welcome. What have been your research efforts to answer this question so far? Cn you share it with us?

Comment: I’ve looked everywhere I’m dying I need help :(

Comment: If you mean that in the very real sense, then you should speak to a member of your medical/surgical team as questions regarding personal medical advice are off-topic here. If it's just an expression of frustration of not being able to find what you're looking for, then I get it. The limiting factor (or a limiting factor) seems to be the process of glucuronidation by the enzyme glucuronosyltransferase (UDPGT), the rate of production of the enzyme being limited. That should be a starting point for research.